# How do you invoke the Foundry SQL Server "Direct Read Engine"?

Tags: palantir-foundry

According to [Foundry documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/analytics-connectivity/architecture/), accessing foundry via SQL over JDBC/ODBC can use two different backends:

- Spark Engine
- Direct Read Engine

Direct Read Engine sounds ideal for extracting large amounts of data with simple filters.

But I can't seem to run simple SQL via ODBC (`pyodbc`) over a large dataset.
Googling turns up little about this feature other than the documentation page above.

My query fits the 4 constraints defined by the documentation:

- Supported backing storage (parquet)
- The query does not require SQL compute
- Columns are basic types, not `array`, `map`, `struct`
- Filtering must be of the form `col op constant` where the operator is one of the following operators: (`=`, `!=`, `<>`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`).

##### Querying a large dataset with a `=` filter:

```sql
SELECT col FROM "/project/my_dataset" WHERE date = ?
```

or

```sql
SELECT col FROM "/project/my_dataset" WHERE date = '2000-01-01'
```

gives an data limit error, suggesting *Spark Engine* was used:

```
Failed to get results - Executing query failed. FAILED_TO_EXECUTE - The result size of this query exceeds the maximum allowed result size of 1g. Please filter down on the number of rows and columns and try aga
in.
```

##### Querying with no filter:

```sql
SELECT col FROM "/project/my_dataset"
```

gives an error:

```
Failed to get results - Query execution failed - INTERNAL (FoundrySqlServer:QueryFailed) with instance ID <my instance guid>
```

which suggests the query is treated differently to the filtered query - perhaps failing to use DRE?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to explicitly select the execution engine, Foundry will select one based on the query. The documentation says:

> Foundry SQL Server will automatically select an execution engine based
> on the complexity of the query. Each execution engine comes with a set
> of tradeoffs for overall performance, result size limitations, and
> supported query complexity.

Comment: Thanks but I can't write a less complex query than 'SELECT col FROM dataset'?

Comment: The documentation states that there are some conditions to be met when direct querying, e.g. that only CSV, Parquet, Avro and Soho as file formats are allowed. Did you make sure that your query meets all the conditions?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question with those details.

Comment: Instead of `pyodbc` I recommend to use the python library Foundry DevTools. https://emdgroup.github.io/foundry-dev-tools/FoundryRestClient_usage.html#pandas-dataframe-from-spark-sql-dialect

Comment: @nicornk That library looks interesting but I'm not sure how it can help with this use case. I simply need to pull out a column with potentially a large amount of data, which is relatively easy with standard ODBC + documented Foundry functionality.
This issue is now with foundry support, I will update it with an answer when I have more information.

Comment: If your dataset is backed by parquet files, doing a SELECT col1 FROM "dataset" should trigger a direct read, at least that is what's happening on our stack. I did the suggestion because it means you do not have to install pyodbc + ODBC drivers. This is usually painful in the python world. Foundry DevTools also falls back to the dataProxy SQL Query endpoint, which might bring you to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Filters don't hit DRE despite the documentation.
There are also multiple bugs in DRE which will hopefully be fixed in time.